# Javascript logic Issue

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable "isOnSecond" which is initially set to false

This is connected to an if statement that detects the boolean value, if it is true some actions are performed and then the boolean is set back to false. therefore I want the action to be performed half the time.

My questions is this, I know I have logic problems in this function however I cant seem to conjure up a solution at this point.

How should I re work this function with my desired logic?

```
function transComplete()
{
    slideTransStep = 0;
    crtSlideIndex = nextSlideIndex;
    alert(isOnSecond);

    // for IE filters, removing filters re-enables cleartype
    if (nextSlide.style.removeAttribute)
        nextSlide.style.removeAttribute("filter");

    // show next slide
    showSlide((crtSlideIndex >= totalSlides) ? 1 : crtSlideIndex + 1);

    if (isOnSecond == true){
    //unhighlight all controls
    for (var i=0; i < slidesControllersCollection.length; i++){
        if (slidesControllersCollection[i].className === slideHighlightClass)
        slidesControllersCollection[i].className = ""; }

    // highlight the control for the next slide
    if (slidesControllersCollection[i].className === slideHighlightClass)       
    document.getElementById("slide-control-" + crtSlideIndex+1).className = slideHighlightClass;

    isOnSecond = false;
    }
    isOnSecond = true;  
}
```

Comment: First I would suggest wrapping all your if statements in `{ }`. But you are always setting `isOnSecond` to `true` at the end, so that's probably the problem

Comment: Thanks Guys, Got it working, school boy error :)

Comment: You need to _properly_ indent your code.  The problems should then be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if (isOnSecond == true) {
>     // do work only every second time
>     isOnSecond = false;
> }
> isOnSecond = true;
> ```

That will *always* set `isOnSecond` to true, even if you had just set it to false right before. Instead, use

```
if (isOnSecond) {
    // do work only every second time
    isOnSecond = false;
} else {
    isOnSecond = true;
}
```

or

```
if (isOnSecond) {
    // do work only every second time
}
isOnSecond = !isOnSecond;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an 'else' at the end, or isOnSecond will always be set to true.

```
if (isOnSecond == true){
    //unhighlight all controls
    //lots of code here
    isOnSecond = false;
} else {
    isOnSecond = true;  
}
```

Comment: That or exit the function before the second value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this === $that) {
    //Logic
    isOnSecond = false;
}

isOnSecond = true;
```

This code will ensure that `isOnSecond` is only ever false for a as long as it takes the interpreter to finish the if statement and move to the next line, which I can assure you is a very short period of time.

It seems that you should loose the `isOnSecond = true` at the end of the function and only declare it true again when you actually need it to be true rather than always.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you run through the if statement

```
if (isOnSecond == true){
     stuff . . .
     isOnSecond = false;
}
```

and then set isOnSecond to true

```
isOnSecond = true;
```

if you do this:

```
if (isOnSecond == true){
     stuff . . .
     isOnSecond = false;
}else{
    isOnSecond = true;
}
```

This will prevent isOnSecond always coming out as 'true'. In other words, if it's set to true, it'll become false and if it's set to false, it'll become true.